# where not in fails if converting datetime columns to date (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord

When I try searching for records that weren't created_on particular days, the conversion from datetime to date fails in the query

```
>> some_days = [Date.parse("2013-12-25"), Date.parse("2013-12-31")]
    => [Wed, 25 Dec 2013, Tue, 31 Dec 2013] 
>> User.where.not("DATE(created_at)" => some_days)
```

errors with:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.DATE(created_at) does not exist
```

It doesn't seem like this is the correct rails behavior. For now, my workaround is this, but I'd like to know the correct way to do this.

```
>> User.where("DATE(created_at) not in (?)", some_days + [Date.new])
```

This workaround doesn't work if the array of dates is empty, which is why I add Date.new to it.

Comment: just an FYI, you might be introducing subtle timezone defect here, users.created_at will be saved as UTC in the database; read more here if you like: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple:

```
User.where.not(created_at: some_days)
```

This is smart enough to handle case with empty array (adds `where 1=1` to a statement)

Update:

As I have finally understood what is the problem, there is a  correct solution.

```
class User
  scope :not_created_at, ->(dates) { where.not(created_at: Array.wrap(dates).map {|date| date..(date + 1.day)} ) }

end

User.not_created_at(some_days)

# Executed query
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (NOT ((("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-12-25' AND '2013-12-26' OR "users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-12-31' AND '2014-01-01') OR 1=0)))
```

Comment: This results in a `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error.

Comment: @zeantsoi Not in rails 4. This is one of greatest changes they've made.

Comment: created_at is a DateTime though, I want to convert it to a Date and match it against an array of Dates

Comment: `User.create(:email => "fake@email.com"); User.where(created_at: [Date.today])` yields `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `

Comment: Updated answer, should cover all cases now.

Comment: This seems just as hacky as my workaround. I guess ultimately I want to use `User.where.not("DATE(created_at)" => some_days)` but am wondering if the reason it doesn't work is because of an ActiveRecord bug.

Comment: The problem with this above is that `Date` is quite slow function, much slower than `BEETWEEN` approach. Also it is not db agnostic - it will only work in mysql.